# Computability: Is the language of DFAs that receive even-length words in P?

Tags: computation-theory, dfa

I've been struggling with this one for a while and am not able to come up with anything. Any pointers would be really appreciated.

The problem is: given the language of all DFAs that receive only words of even-length, prove whether it is in P or not.

I've considered making a turing machine that goes over the given DFA in something like BFS/Dijkstra's algorithm in order to find all the paths from the starting state to the accepting one, but have no idea how to handle loops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's in P, at worst quadratic. Each state of the DFA can have four parity states

1. unvisited  -- state 0
2. known to be reachable in an odd number of steps  -- state 1
3. known to be reachable in an even number of steps  -- state 2
4. known to be reachable in both, odd and even numbers of steps  -- state 3

Mark all states as unvisited, put the starting state in a queue (FIFO, priority, whatever), set its parity state to 2.

```
child_parity(n)
    switch(n)
        case 0: error 
        case 1: return 2
        case 2: return 1
        case 3: return 3

while(queue not empty)
    dfa_state <- queue
    step_parity = child_parity(dfa_state.parity_state)
    for next_state in dfa_state.children
        old_parity = next_state.parity_state
        next_state.parity_state |= step_parity
        if old_parity != next_state.parity_state // we have learnt something new
            add next_state to queue // remove duplicates if applicable
for as in accept_states
    if as.parity_state & 1 == 1
        return false
return true
```

Unless I'm overlooking something, each DFA state is treated at most twice, each time checking at most `size` children for required action.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem this only requires two states.

Your entry state would be empty string, and would also be an accept state. Adding anythign to the string would move it to the next state, which we can call the 'odd' state, and not make it an accept state. Adding another string puts us back to the original state.

I guess I'm not sure on the terminology anymore of whether a language is in P or not, so if you gave me a definition there I could tell you if this fits it, but this is one of the simplest DFA's around...

Comment: Thanks for your time! Unfortunately, the question is not about actually building a DFA that accepts /all/ even-length words, but the problem of deciding whether a given DFA accepts only even-length words

Comment: I see your problem better now. Might I ask then, what exactly is the definition of a language being in P? Being in P in relation to what? I've only ever seen it used in time and computational complexity, and to be honest you don't get much use of this course once you're out of uni :)